# How ot write points into influxdb 0.8 with time in seconds

Tags: influxdb

I would like to write points into an influx 0.8 database with the time values given in seconds through HTTP. Here's a sample point in JSON format:

```
[
    {
        "points": [
            [
                1435692857.0,
                897
            ]
        ],
        "name": "some_series",
        "columns": [
            "time",
            "value"
        ]
    }
]
```

The documentation is unclear what the format of time values should be (nano or milli seconds?) and how to specify to influxdb what to expect. Currently I'm using a query parameter: `precision=s`

That seems to work fine, the server returns HTTP Status code 200 as expected. When querying against the database using influx' admin interface using `select * from some_series` the datapoints in the table are returned with the expected timestamp. On the graph however, the time axis is indexed with fractions of seconds and queries like `select * from some_series where time > now() - 1h` dont yield any results.

I assume that there is something wrong with the timestamps. I tried multiplying my value by 1000 but then nothing gets inserted into the database with no visible errors.

Whats the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution! The problem was only in part with the precision. Your answer was correct, the query parameter is called `time_precision` and I should post integers instead of floats. Which was probably the first thing I attempted with no results...

However, due to some time zone problems, my **time values where in the future relative to server time** and by default, any select statement includes a `where time < now()` statement. So, in fact values were written into the database, but not displayed because of that hidden where statement. The solution was to tell the database to return "future" values, too:

```
select value from some_series where time < now() + 1h
```

Answer (score 1):

By default, supplied timestamps are assumed to be in milliseconds. I think your writes are defaulting to milliseconds because the query string parameter should be `time_precision=s`, not `precision=s`.

See the details under "Time Precision on Written Data" on https://influxdb.com/docs/v0.8/api/reading_and_writing_data.html.

I also think the `time` value should be an integer rather than a float. I'm not sure how to explain the other behaviors, where the timestamp seems to be the right date and multiplying by 1000 doesn't solve the issue, but I wonder if it's related to writing floats.

Please contact the InfluxDB support team at support@influxdb.com for further assistance.